# How to trigger a downstream job if a condition is met in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jobs

I have a multiphase job CD which has two downstream Job CD-Sim CD-Art, I want trigger the jobs based on condition. if deploy = Art then trigger CD-Art this job and if deploy = Sim then trigger CD-Sim job..

How can i accomplish this using shell script by using execute shell option?

Answer (score 1):

If your deploy condition can be evaluated with an environment variable ($DEPLOY for example), you can use the [Conditional BuildStep](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin) plugin.

You have to create two conditional steps like below:

[image]

Plus another one to launch the CD-sim job if $DEPLOY=sim

Comment: Hey thanks @Bruno, can you tell me how can i us the console output of the build to trigger the job. I mean i have a Response: 
{"status":"success","results":{}}
********************* Polling Started
Current Time: 1464766896431
Patterns: "build_status":"complete">>"build_status":"failed"
{"results":"status":"success"} output. how can I use status to trigger  a job

Comment: Here is solution I've posted a few weeks ago to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35599242/jenkins-how-do-i-make-the-color-of-a-failed-build-due-to-a-workspace-issue-from/37136452#37136452